# Apply a function if value from one dataframe exists in another dataframe with Dask

Tags: python, dataframe, dask

I have 2 dask dataframes:

```
control_values = dd.DataFrame({'name': ['V1', 'V2', 'V3', 'V4'],'val':[2,3,5,6]})
values_to_control = dd.DataFrame({'name': ['V2', 'V4'],'val':[29,23]})
```

I need to apply a control function to the `val` of `values_to_control` using the `val` from `control_values` dataset where the names are the same.

With pandas I do something like follow:

```
sum_values = lambda s1, s2: s1 + s2

result=values_to_control.set_index('name').combine(control_values.set_index('name'),sum_values).reset_index()
result = result[result['val'].notna()]
```

The result should like:

```
name  val
V2    32 
V4    29
```

There is a way to do that using dask Dataframes?

Comment: It’s not super clear what you’re trying to do. Can you show us what you’ve tried? Or maybe an implementation in pandas that you’re trying to scale to dask?

Comment: @MichaelDelgado I have update with an implementation on pandas

Comment: It seems like you’re just setting name as the index and then adding. You can do this - there’s no need for all the wrapper functions. Just `df.set_index('name)` and then add. Check out the dask [user guide section on best practices](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/dataframe-best-practices.html#use-the-index) - setting indexes are expensive and you should consider the performance implications when structuring your workflow.